# Getting error in Nested Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a alphaNumeric column(`invoice_no`) in my mysql Database having values like this `INV0001` and many values like `INVI000040` and now I have made one more column that is `invoice_prefix` so I want to seperate the the integer and alphabetic parts of `invoice_no` into `invoice_no` and `invoice_prefix`  so I have written one query  to extract the alphanumeric part of the `invoice_no`

`SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE    ( REPLACE(x.invoice_no, '9', ''), '8', ''), '7', ''), '6', ''), '5', ''), '4', ''),         '3', ''), '2', ''), '1', ''), '0', '') as alpha_only FROM user_invoices as x where x.id = 1 and x.invoice_no REGEXP '^[A-Z]'`

and this query is also giving correct output but when I am trying to update all the columns which are having this kind of invoice_no 
and for that I have written query like this

```
  update user_invoices 
     set user_invoices.invoice_prefix = 
     ( select invoice_prefix 
      from (
    SELECT
         invoice_no,
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                REPLACE(invoice_no, '9', ''), '8', ''), '7', ''), '6', ''), '5', ''), '4', ''),
                 '3', ''), '2', ''), '1', ''), '0', '') AS alpha_only
        FROM user_invoices as x 
  where x.id = 1 and x.invoice_no REGEXP '^[A-Z]'
    )
     ) where id = 1;
```

But when I am running this query I am getting this error

> Every derived table must have its own alias

I am not able to understand where I am doing mistake

Comment: Add table alias after each subquery's end `)`.

Comment: can u please edit this query

Comment: See that bracket that's one row above the bottom row, where there's just a bracket on its own(?), change `)` to `) a` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a subquery?  Based on your description, this should do what you want:

```
update user_invoices ui
   set ui.invoice_prefix = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              REPLACE(ui.invoice_no, '9', ''), '8', ''), '7', ''), '6', ''), '5', ''), '4', ''),
               '3', ''), '2', ''), '1', ''), '0', '')
   where ui.invoice_no regexp '[0-9]';
```